# Java Design Scenario

Tags: java

I have a function in java that receives a SOAP request(a java object) and validates request parameters. This request will be further used for business logic once validated. While validating the request, if the function finds invalid parameter it tries to rectify it and change its value. That means, the request object received as a function argument would be modified. The function can't create a new request and fill it with valid parameters and then return it because the function is already returning a response object.

So, the question now is, is it a correct way to change the state of object coming as input parameter? I think its not, because the calling function has no idea that the passed object state is getting modified unless we mention it in java doc and the caller read is carefully.

Any alternates?

Comment: How about returning an error? Include information about which parameter has failed validation and what its valid values are. As you said: It is commonly a bad idea to change parameters without the client's knowledge.

Comment: You can flag the object that it has been changed with a boolean field. Then you can check the request object later to see if it has been modified and do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a Map of "validated"/"corrected" parameters and add it as a request attribute.
You can send this object with the response to let the caller see what data was actually processed.

If you can avoid it, I would not not send a request object to business a logic function but send just the validated data.

Also, keep in mind that trying to "change" request parameters is tricky & dangerous. One of the common ways to hack a system is to send unexpected input and see if the system will process it (SQL injection, passing scripts as innocent text...).